# Service Fabric Web API Versioning issue

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-service-fabric, api-versioning

I'm working on a service fabric project with multiple stateless services. When i try to add versioning as in the code below

```
[Authorize]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class SessionController : Controller
{
...
}
```

it's not working when calling the service later using Postman or using some client winforms app i made just to call this service. And when i say it's not working i mean it's not looking for a specific version i placed in the controller.

e.g.
I'm calling **http://localhost:1234/api/v1.0/session/set-session** and as you can see in my controller i only have version 2.0. Now my API gets hit this way or another no matter what version number i put in.

I added code to the Startup.cs

```
services.AddApiVersioning(options => {
       options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(2, 0);
       options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
       options.ReportApiVersions = true;
       options.ApiVersionReader = new HeaderApiVersionReader("x-api-version");
});
```

Specific API call looks like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("set-session")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> SetSession([FromBody] SessionModel model)
 { ... }
```

Can anyone tell me what am i missing or maybe api versioning is not supported in service fabric at all?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does your solution work locally? Based on what I see, I would suspect - no. This should have nothing to do with Service Fabric at all.

#### Issue 1

I see that your base class inherits from `Controller`, which is allowed, but is usually `ControllerBase`. No concern there, just FYI. The crux of the problem is *likely* that your controller has not applied the `[ApiController]` attribute. API Versioning defines `IApiControllerSpecification` and `IApiControllerFilter`, which is used to filter which controllers should be considered an API. This is important for developers building applications that have the UI and API parts mixed. A controller is a controller in ASP.NET Core and it was difficult to distinguish these two in the early days. There is now a built-in `IApiControllerSpecification` that considers any controller with `[ApiController]` applied to be an API. This can be changed, replaced, or completely disabled using `ApiVersioningOptions.UseApiBehavior = false`.

If your library/application is only APIs, you can decorate all controllers at once using:

```cs
[assembly: ApiController]
```

Since your controller is not currently being considered an API, all requests matching the route are being directed there. The value `1.0` is being considered an arbitrary string rather than an API version. This is why it matches at all instead of HTTP 400. I suspect you must only have one API and it is defined as `2.0`; otherwise, I would expect an `AmbiguousActionException`.

#### Issue 2

Your example shows that you are trying to version by URL segment, but you've configured the options to only consider the header `x-api-version`. This option should be configured with one of the following:

**URL Segment (only)**

```cs
options.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
```

**URL Segment and Header**

```cs
// registration order is irrelevant
options.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(
    new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader(),
    new HeaderApiVersionReader("x-api-version"));
```

**Default (Query String and URL Segment)**

```cs
// NOTE: this is the configuration
// options.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(
//    new QueryStringApiVersionReader(),
//    new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader());
```

**Side Note**

As defined, using the URL segment and header versioning methodologies don't make sense. You have a single route which requires an API version. A client will always have to include the API version in every request so there is no point to also supporting a header.

If you define 2 routes, then it makes sense:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]                       // match by header
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")] // match by url segment
```

> Versioning by URL segment, while common, is the least RESTful. It violates the *Uniform Interface* constraint. This issue demonstrates yet another problem with that approach. Query string, header, media type, or any combination thereof will all work with the single route template of: `[Route("api/[controller]")]`

#### Observation 1

You have configured `options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true`. This will have **no effect** when versioning by URL segment. It is impossible to provide a default value of route parameter in the middle of a template. The same would be true for `api/value/{id}/subvalues` if `{id}` is not specified.

This option **will** have an effect if you:

- Add a second route template that doesn't have the API version parameter
- You update your versioning strategy to not use a URL segment

> It should be noted that is a highly abused feature. It is meant to *grandfather* in existing services that didn't previously have explicit versioning because adding it will break existing clients. You should be cognizant of that if that isn't your use case.

Comment: Yeap, you are right regarding everything. 

I cleared versioning configuration in Startup.cs and decorated controller with [ApiController] and that worked well. When i call api with wrong version i'm getting UnsupportedApiVersion response and when right version of api is called then i'm getting correct response back. 

Thanks a lot man. I will vote for this answer as a correct one but lack of my reputation will not allow it to be visible to others.